# Using a single ffmpeg instance to transcode multiple RTSP streams to HLS - not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use a single instance of `ffmpeg` to convert multiple RTSP streams to HLS. The command I am using is this: (I've broken it up into multiple lines so its easier to read)

The problem I am facing is that ffmpeg is writing the same video stream (url1) to both directories m1 and m2 when I look at the generated ts files. What am I doing wrong? Both url1 and url2 are valid. If I break up the command to two different `ffmpeg` processes it works just fine.

Thanks.

```
 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i rtsp://url1 -fflags flush_packets 
 -max_delay 2 -flags -global_header -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 3 
 -hls_segment_filename m1/video%03d.ts -hls_flags delete_segments 
 -vcodec copy -y m1/video1.m3u8 
 -i rtsp://url2 -fflags flush_packets 
 -max_delay 2 -flags -global_header -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 3 
 -hls_segment_filename m2/video%03d.ts -hls_flags delete_segments 
 -vcodec copy -y m2/video2.m3u8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg requires a syntax of the form

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 ... -i inputn output1 output2 ... outputn
```

with `-map` options set to indicate routing of inputs to outputs.

So,

```
 -i rtsp://url1 -i rtsp://url2
 -map 0 -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 2 -flags -global_header 
 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_segment_filename m1/video%03d.ts 
 -hls_flags delete_segments -vcodec copy -y m1/video1.m3u8
 -map 1 -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 2 -flags -global_header 
 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_segment_filename m2/video%03d.ts 
 -hls_flags delete_segments -vcodec copy -y m2/video1.m3u8
```

Comment: Thank you. I just found map while you answered - it solved my problem