# FFMPEG - Multiple inputs on multiple outputs

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, stream, type-conversion, udp

I would like to input multiple web radios and output them on multiple different UDP multicasts. I almost succeded but the problem is FFMPEG puts always the same exact radio on all of the outputs. Seems like it choses a specific radio from all the inputs.

I tried using the -map parameter but it didn't change the result.

This is the command i use:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -i "http://listen.181fm.com:8052" -map 0 -f mpegts "udp://239.0.0.1:12345?localaddr=172.16.10.116" -thread_queue_size 1024 -i "http://listen.181fm.com:8126" -map 1 -f mpegts "udp://239.0.0.2:12345?localaddr=172.16.10.116"
```

FFMPEG  always choses http://listen.181fm.com:8126 as an output. Twice in my case.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47250795/5726027

Comment: I just tested it here. The outputs are different. But ffmpeg duplicates the tags from one of the inputs, when displaying output info.

Comment: Thank you Mulvya. You are indeed right. The output is indeed different between the two outputs. It is actually just the duplicate output tag info. Any idea if this can be fixed?

Comment: Got it. You need to specify the output metadata. So for instance adding the parameter -map_metadata 2 to output would take the Metadata from input 2 and adding it to that corresponding output.